# --- Logging error --- Python and Django 2.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.2

**Python Script**

```
from django.conf import settings
import django
import sys
import json
sys.path.append("/srv/vhosts")
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
django.setup()
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("project")
logger.error("saveLog Error: ")
```

**Setting**

```
LOG_ROOT = "/srv/volume1/logs/project"
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {"require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"}},
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%y %b %d, %H:%M:%S",
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
        },
        "project": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": LOG_ROOT + "/project.log",
        },
        "file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": LOG_ROOT + "/debug.log",
        },
        "django_file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": LOG_ROOT + "/django.log",
        },
        "console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler"},
        "celery": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": LOG_ROOT + "/celery.log",
            # 'formatter': 'simple',
            "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "project": {"handlers": ["sia"], "level": "DEBUG", "propagate": True},

    },
}
```

after running script `python  Script.py` getting an error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 547, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'user'
Call stack:
  File "job_launch.py", line 20, in <module>
    logger.error("saveLog Error: ")
Message: 'saveLog Error: '
Arguments: ()
```

ENV:

Python : 3.6
Django : 2.2
OS : Centos 7